# How can I implement pairwise query-dependent learning-to-rank in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

**The problem:**

I am setting up a product that utilizes Azure Search, and one of the requirements is that the results of a search conduct multi-stage learning-to-rank where the final stage involves a *pairwise query-dependent machine-learned model* such as RankNet.

Is there any existing support in Azure Search for this? If not, where in the Azure Search pipeline would you recommend I start?

**What I have tried:**

I had been hoping to find something similar to the [ElasticSearch LTR Plugin](https://elasticsearch-learning-to-rank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but have not been able to.

The only option I can currently think of is to set-up a server which forwards the query from the front-end to Azure Search, re-ranks the search results my pairwise LTR methods, reconstructs the re-ranked search results, and sends those to the front-end.

However, I am very apprehensive about the inefficiency of this option and it would be unnecessary if there is an existing way for me to do this.

**Language / Libraries**

If relevant: I am coding primarily in C# and would be using [CNTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK) for machine-learning.

Comment: If down-voting, please comment an explanation so that the question may be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, your suggestion is the way to go. Azure Search does not currently offer a way to inject a custom ranker within the search pipeline. You would need to config your query to return a large amount of results and then re-rank yourself.  Sorry we do not have a better answer than this right now. If you have time, it would be great if you could [cast your vote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/18628708-add-machine-learned-ranking-models) for this here as we are hearing this more often lately.

Comment: Vote cast. My fully Azure solution would then be an Azure Search and Azure Machine Learning Service connected by an Azure Microservice.